# Accessing server connected to second router

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, router

Re: Accessing web server on second router.

We’ve had a retail store, opencart website since 2014 hosted on a VPS server through VPSBlocks. As the monthly fees are increasing, currently at AUD$179 per month, we've decided to setup a physical web server to host the website and have it connected at our home office instead.

-Installed an evaluation version of windows 2012 R2 standard on a Dell OptiPlex server, along with the website.
-Connected 2 iinet modem routers to the home Lan after switching to the iinet business bundle. 
Static ips received from iiNet: 203.xx.xx.40 through to 203.5xx.xx.43 and i am aware i can only use .41 and .42 for any devices.

Router 1 (R1) settings: 
-DHCP turned on – for all mobile phones, tablets and computers to connect through wifi - Tested and working well. No landline/voip phones

Router 2 (R2) settings: 
-Connected one end of the Ethernet cable to a Lan port on R1 and connected the other end to the WAN port on R2
-DHCP turned off 
- I've changed the gateway ip to 203.xx.xx.40
- Added the new ip range (start .41 end .43)
- Added a static ip reservation for 203.xx.xx.41 on R2 as well as adding the static ip through the TCP v4 adapter settings on the web server – Tested and I can browse the internet on the web server.
- Port forwarding has been set on R2 for port 3389
- Port blocking has been turned off through the iinet Toolbox settings as well.

Goal 1: To be able to RDP to the server from computers outside of the network.
Goal 2: For customers to be able to browse the website on the server. Website files will be moved to the new server once goal 1 has been resolved.

I understand that purchasing a commercial router will resolve the issue but I’m hoping there is someone out there who’s experienced this and could make it work with the current setup. All suggestions welcomed and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Installed an evaluation version of windows 2012 R2 standard on a Dell OptiPlex server` - Why would you use Windows Server 2012 R2 instead of Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019? Also, the Optiplex is not a server, it's a desktop. Using it as a server does not make it a server.

Comment: Noted.. regarding the server version. Since it's an evaluation, i'll update it to 2016 or 2019 and provide some feedback after. My apologies as i'm not sure why i added Optiplex. It's a Dell Poweredge T420.